# How to write ast-grep rules in these case?

Tags: ast-grep

I am using [ast-grep](https://github.com/ast-grep/ast-grep) to refactor my javascript code, but in some cases, I don't know how to write ast-grep rules to fix them.

```js
const a = require(`${ROOT}/common`) // expect to be: const a = require('@/common')

const b = require(`@/utils/index.js`) // expect to be: const b = require('@/utils')
```

I try to fix the case in [ast-grep playground](https://ast-grep.github.io/playground.html#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).

My expect:

```js
const a = require(`${ROOT}/common`) // expect to be: const a = require('@/common')

const b = require(`@/utils/index.js`) // expect to be: const b = require('@/utils')
```

Answer (score 1):

I find the answer in ast-grep docs. I can use transform api to fix

[answer link](https://ast-grep.github.io/playground.html#eyJtb2RlIjoiQ29uZmlnIiwibGFuZyI6ImphdmFzY3JpcHQiLCJxdWVyeSI6InJlcXVpcmUoJEEgKyAkQikiLCJyZXdyaXRlIjoicmVxdWlyZSgnQCRCJykiLCJjb25maWciOiIjIFlBTUwgUnVsZSBpcyBtb3JlIHBvd2VyZnVsIVxuIyBodHRwczovL2FzdC1ncmVwLmdpdGh1Yi5pby9ndWlkZS9ydWxlLWNvbmZpZy5odG1sI3J1bGVcbnJ1bGU6XG4gIGFsbDpcbiAgICAtIHBhdHRlcm46IHJlcXVpcmUoJEEpXG4gICAgLSByZWdleDogcmVxdWlyZVxcKGBcXCRcXHtST09UXFx9LitgXFwpXG4gICMgYW55OlxuICAgICMgLSBwYXR0ZXJuOiByZXF1aXJlKCRBKVxudHJhbnNmb3JtOlxuICBCOlxuICAgIHN1YnN0cmluZzpcbiAgICAgIHNvdXJjZTogJEFcbiAgICAgIHN0YXJ0Q2hhcjogOFxuICAgICAgZW5kQ2hhcjogLTFcbmZpeDpcbiAgcmVxdWlyZSgnQCRCJykiLCJzb3VyY2UiOiIvLyBjb25zb2xlLmxvZygpIHdpbGwgYmUgbWF0Y2hlZCBieSBwYXR0ZXJuIVxuLy8gY2xpY2sgZGlmZiB0YWIgdG8gc2VlIHJld3JpdGUuXG5cbmNvbnN0IGEgPSByZXF1aXJlKGAke1JPT1R9L2NvbW1vbmApXG5jb25zdCBiID0gcmVxdWlyZShgQC9jb21tb25gKSJ9)

fix detail:

In essence, this rule is designed to find `require` calls with a specific pattern and transform the argument by taking a substring and then fixing the call by prepending an `'@'` to the argument. This could be part of a larger effort to standardize the way modules are required in a codebase.

Here's a breakdown of the rule:

- **Rule Section**: It defines a set of conditions that must all be met (`all` clause) for the rule to apply.

  - `pattern: require($A)`: This looks for any `require` function calls with a single argument and assigns that argument to variable `$A`.
  - `regex: require\(`${ROOT}.+`\)`: This uses a regular expression to match `require` function calls that use template literals with a variable `ROOT` at the beginning, followed by any other characters.
- **Transform Section**: It specifies how to transform the code if the rule conditions are met.

  - `B`: This creates a new variable `B`.
  - `substring`: This operation takes a substring of variable `$A`.
  - `source: $A`: The source string is the value captured in `$A`.
  - `startChar: 8`: The substring starts from the 8th character of `$A`.
  - `endChar: -1`: The substring ends one character before the end of `$A`.
- **Fix Section**: It defines the code replacement that should be made if the rule is triggered.

  - `require('@$B')`: This replaces the original `require` call with a new one that has `'@'` prepended to the transformed argument `$B`.